# How to fix overlapping ledsidenotes?

Tags: reledmac

I am using `reledmac` to annotate my line numbers to effectively create verse numbers for an old Bible I am typesetting. However, this means that I can no longer use `\marginpar` for my margin notes. So, I switched to `\ledsidenote` (specifically `\ledouternote`). However, now, the margin notes overlap each other. Also, sometimes the notes ends where I refer to it in the text when I want the beginning of the margin note to align with where I call for it in the text. How do I fix these issues with the actual location of the margin notes with `\ledouternote`?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside,10pt]{book}
\usepackage[paperheight=9in,paperwidth=6in,inner=1.in,outer=1.25in,top=0.6in,bottom=0.6in,heightrounded,marginpar=1.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage[noresetlinenumannotation, series={A}, noend,noeledsec,nofamiliar,noledgroup]{reledmac}
\newcommand{\bv}[1]{\linenumannotation{#1}}
\makeatletter
\Xwraplinenumannotation{\@firstofone}
\renewcommand{\linenumrep}[1]{}
\makeatother
\Xnoidenticallinenumannotation
\linenummargin{inner}
\sidenotemargin{outer}
\begin{document}
The \bv{1} booke of the *  
\ledouternote{This Goſpel is moſt ſolemly ſung in holy Church at Matins upon Chriſtmas day.}
generation of  {\scshape Jesus}  Christ, the ſonne of David, the ſonne of Abraham.\par
†\bv{2}* \ledouternote{As alſo it is the Goſpel of the \textbf{\emph{Conception}} and \textbf{\emph{Nativitie}} of our Blessed Lady: becauſe here is declared the pedegree of her alſo.}
Abraham begat Iſaac,
\pend
\endnumbering
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you post `MWE` of your code?

Comment: ỳes, please. In each post, we nee MWE.

Comment: Sorry, added it.

Answer (score 2):

The problem of overlapping can't be solved easily. If you don't have any place to put your note, they will overlap. However, you have 3 solutions to deal with it.

1. Set the font size of your note
2. Have larger margin. By default the sidenote get the full width of the margin (`\marginparwidth`, cf. § 12.2.1 of the reledmac handbook)
3. Shift the place you call the notes.

To set the vertical alignment of the sidenote, you can use

```
\rightnoteupfalse
\leftnoteupfalse
```

cf 12.2.2